# convergence in $L^1$ for a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series

If we have a sequence $(f_n)$, which is convergence in measure to $f$. If we can prove that a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$. Can we say that the original sequence converges to $f$ in $L^1$ as well? If not, what extra conditions do we need?

Thanks！

Comment: To do nested underscores, do this: f_{n_k} for $f_{n_k}$.

Comment: If you have a sequence of *real numbers* $x_n$ such that any subsequence $x_{n_k}$ has a further subsequence $x_{n_{k_\ell}}$ which converges to $L$, which doesn't depend on the subsequence you started with, then $x_n \to L$. This can be used in a metric space to prove that $f_n \to f$, by considering $x_n=d(f_n,f)$. It cannot be applied in general topological spaces; in particular it does not apply to the topology of pointwise convergence. At any rate, it applies here, by considering $x_n=\| f_n - f \|_{L^1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a counterexample.

Consider $f\equiv0$ and the sequence $f_n$ given by
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) =\begin{cases}
1/n &\text{if $\vert x \vert \leq 1/n$}\\
0 &\text{if $\vert x \vert > 1/n$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*} 
if $n$ is odd, and 
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) =\begin{cases}
n^2 &\text{if $\vert x \vert \leq 1/n$}\\
0 &\text{if $\vert x \vert > 1/n$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
if $n$ is even

We see that the sequence converges in measure to $f$, and also the subsequence $f_n$ with $n$ odd, converges to $f$ in $L^1$, however the subsequence $f_n$, with $n$ even, doesn't converge to $f$ in $L^1$, as we have 
\begin{equation*}
\Vert f_n-f \Vert_1=\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}n^2dx=2n
\end{equation*}

An extra condition to secure that the sequence will converge in $L^1$ is if the difference between $f_n$ and $f$ is bounded a.e. However, I don't know if there are weaker extra conditions which secure convergence in $L^1$.

Comment: This is correct. But we can think a bit more "big picture" than this, Just proving *some* subsequence converges in $L^1$ is useless: We can always take some horrible sequence and interlace a convergent sequence with it, to get a new sequence which has a convergent subsequence. That doesn't make our new sequence converge. What you actually need to do is to be able to extract a convergent subsequence from your original sequence, using only properties that are shared by all of its subsequences.